# WebStorm/IDEA JavaScript debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, intellij-idea, webstorm

The problem is that when I specified all debug configuration in WebStorm I also need to specify debug URL (local file or remote server URL) to start debugging. Then I click on debug button and it opens me a new tab in browser with that URL and debugging enabled only for that tab via Chrome extension.

My question: is there any way to run debug on the page that is already opened in my browser?

For example I have `mydomain.com/*`, where `*` - can be any URL, so I want to debug every page on my `mydomain.com` and not to open new page with exact URL (that I typed inside my debug configuration) every time I run debug from WebStorm. It's just annoying and wasting so much time. Can debug be attached to one tab every time it launches?

Answer (score 1):

Normally debugger attaches to already open browser tab with URL matching the one in your Run configuration, new tab is only opened if matching one hasn't been found.
Note that you can start the debug session from browser: open your URL in Crome, right-click the page and choose `Inspect in WebStorm`:

[image]

Comment: let me try starting it right from browser, but what you say about not opening new tab if url is the same true - but if for example i have mydomain.com/catalog opened in my browser tab and inside webstorm ulr is specified like mydomain.com/products or something like that ? I don't know if i can specify something like mydomain.com/* to handle all urls starting with mydomain.com. Thanks.

Comment: you can't. URL of the page being debugged should exactly match the URL of your currently opened tab. Debugger won't attach to mydomain.com/products when you start debugging mydomain.com/catalog